# Ring buffer for audio processing

Tags: c++, circular-list

Below is my source code for the implementation of a Ring/Circular buffer for use in audio processing. I have been using this implementation for several months now but I have some doubts about the efficiency of the insertion and removal functions as well as the correctness/necessity of my usage of `std::atomic<size_t>`type index variables. The execution speed of the read and write functions is crucial to the overall execution speed of the DSP callbacks using these buffers so I would like to know if anyone can suggest any improvements to my design.

```
class Buffer {
    public:
        Buffer();
        Buffer(size_t size);
        Buffer(Buffer const& other);
        Buffer& operator=(Buffer const& other);
        virtual ~Buffer();
        DSG::DSGSample& operator[](size_t const& index);
        inline size_t const& Size()const;
    protected:
        DSG::DSGSample* _buffer;
        size_t _size;
    };
    inline size_t const& DSG::Buffer::Size()const{
        return _size;
    }
//implementation
DSG::Buffer::Buffer():_size(0),_buffer(nullptr){}
DSG::Buffer::Buffer(size_t size):_size(size),_buffer(new DSG::DSGSample[size]){}
DSG::Buffer::Buffer(Buffer const& other) {
    _buffer = new  DSG::DSGSample[_size];
    _size = other._size;
       *this = other;
}
DSG::Buffer& DSG::Buffer::operator=(Buffer const& other){
    if (_size!=other._size) {
        if (_buffer!=nullptr) {
            delete [] _buffer;
        }
        _size = other._size;
        _buffer = new  DSG::DSGSample[_size];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<_size; ++i) {
        _buffer[i] = other._buffer[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
DSG::Buffer::~Buffer(){
    if (_buffer!=nullptr) {
        delete [] _buffer;
    }
}
DSG::DSGSample& DSG::Buffer::operator[](size_t const& index){
#ifdef DEBUG
    assert(index<_size);
#endif
    return _buffer[index];
}

//ringbuffer
class RingBuffer:public DSG::Buffer {
    protected:
        std::atomic<size_t> _write;
        std::atomic<size_t> _read;
        size_t _count;
        size_t MASK;
        size_t write;
        size_t read;
        inline size_t next(size_t current);
        inline size_t make_pow_2(size_t number);
    public:
        RingBuffer();
        RingBuffer(const size_t size);
        RingBuffer(RingBuffer& buffer);
        RingBuffer& operator=(RingBuffer& buffer);
        virtual ~RingBuffer();
        inline bool Write(const DSGSample& elem);
        inline bool Read(DSG::DSGSample& elem);
        inline size_t const& Count()const;
        inline bool Full()const;
        inline bool Empty()const;
        inline void Flush();
        friend bool operator>>(DSG::DSGSample const& signal,DSG::RingBuffer& buffer){
            return buffer.Write(signal);
        }
        friend bool operator<<(DSG::DSGSample& signal,DSG::RingBuffer& buffer){
            return buffer.Read(signal);
        }
#ifdef DEBUG
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,DSG:: RingBuffer const& buffer){
            if (!buffer.Empty()) {
                size_t index= buffer._read;
                size_t count=buffer.Count();
                size_t size = buffer.Size();
                for (int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
                    os<<index<<": "<<buffer._buffer[index]<<std::endl;
                    index = ((index+1)%size);
                }
            }return os;
        }
#endif
    };
    inline bool DSG::RingBuffer::Full()const{
        return _count==this->_size;
    }
    inline bool DSG::RingBuffer::Empty()const{
        return _count==0;
    }
    inline void DSG::RingBuffer::Flush(){
        _write.store(0,std::memory_order_relaxed);
        _read.store(0,std::memory_order_relaxed);
        _count=0;
    }
    inline bool DSG::RingBuffer::Write(const DSGSample& elem){
        if (!Full()) {
            write = _write.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
            _write.store(next(write),std::memory_order_release);
            this->_buffer[write] = elem;
            ++_count;
            return true;
        }else return false;
    }
    inline bool DSG::RingBuffer::Read(DSGSample& elem){
        if (!Empty()) {
            read = _read.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
            _read.store(next(read),std::memory_order_release);
            elem = this->_buffer[read];
            --_count;
            return true;
        }else return false;
    }
    inline size_t const& DSG::RingBuffer::Count()const{
        return _count;
    }
    //note: RingBuffer implementation will force a power of 2 size to allow use of bitwise increment.
    inline size_t DSG::RingBuffer::next(size_t current){return (current+1) & MASK;}
    inline size_t DSG::RingBuffer::make_pow_2(size_t number){
        return pow(2, ceil(log(number)/log(2)));
    }
//implementation
DSG:: RingBuffer::RingBuffer():Buffer(0),_read(0),_write(0),_count(0),MASK(0){}
DSG:: RingBuffer::RingBuffer(const size_t size):Buffer(make_pow_2(size)),_read(0),_write(0),_count(0){
    MASK = this->_size-1;
}
DSG:: RingBuffer::RingBuffer(RingBuffer& buffer):Buffer(buffer){
    _write.store(buffer._write.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
    _read.store(buffer._read.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
    _count = buffer._count;
    MASK = buffer._size-1;
}
DSG:: RingBuffer& DSG:: RingBuffer::operator=(RingBuffer& buffer){
    Buffer::operator=(buffer);
    _write.store(buffer._write.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
    _read.store(buffer._read.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
    _count = buffer._count;
    MASK = buffer._size-1;
    return *this;
}
DSG:: RingBuffer::~RingBuffer(){Flush();}
```

NOTE: `DSG::` is the namespace that encloses all of the code. I have removed the namespace declaration in the code I have posted to cut down on code length.

Comment: What's the use case?  Are there multiple threads reading/writing from this ringbuffer simultaneously?

Comment: @JS1 the buffer is intended to be used in a audio processing system where it acts as the storage device for audio data as the data is passed in-between multiple processing routines. I was considering the possibility of breaking the processing up between multiple threads.

Comment: I have asked a follow up question that contains an updated version of the code up for review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93176/ring-buffer-for-audio-processing-follow-up

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Some basic comments**

As a small point to begin with, I think your code to do with some more whitespace, especially when starting a new method. The way it is currently, it's very densely packed, which makes it harder to read.

Your `operator=` has no exception safety, and does not check for self-assignment. The copy and swap idiom is the easiest way to fix this (if you implement a `swap` function). If not, always remember to allocate the new buffer **before** deleting the old one; if `new` throws, this will then leave everything in a consistent state. Further, `delete` is a no-op on a `nullptr`, so doing the check isn't needed.

```
DSG::Buffer& DSG::Buffer::operator=(Buffer const& other)
{
    if(this != &other) {
        if(_size == other._size) {
            std::copy(other._buffer, other._buffer + other._size, _buffer);
        }
        else {
            new_buf = new  DSG::DSGSample[other._size];
            std::copy(other._buffer, other._buffer + other._size, new_buf);
            delete[] _buffer;
            _size = other._size;
            _buffer = new_buf;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Same again with the destructor: the `nullptr` check isn't needed.

Depending on what you have available to you, using a `std::vector` may be a better choice, as it will free you from having to write all of this.

You use the pattern `}else return false;` a few times. This looks clunky. Just separate it onto a new line and `return false`.

```
if(some_condition) {
   ....
  return true;
}
return false;
```

---

**Multithreading Issues**

If you were planning on make this work in a multithreaded environment, you have quite a lot of work to do. For a start:

- Your `_count` variable will need to be atomic. `Full`, `Empty`, `Write` and `Read` are all completely non-threadsafe at the moment.
- Using `memory_order_relaxed` triggers massive warning bells. Unless you 100% know what you are doing, aren't working on x86(-64), have profiled the hell out of your code and KNOW that it is causing a bottleneck, you should avoid using `memory_order_relaxed`. In this case, if you were in a multithreaded environment, it is almost certainly wrong.

To expand upon why this is wrong in this situation, the most important thing to know about `memory_order_relaxed` is that it does *no inter-thread synchronization*. If you have one thread that calls `Flush()`, and another thread that calls `Read()`, there is absolutely no guarantee that the `Read()` thread will see the update from `Flush()`.

In fact, most of your methods will likely need locks. Suppose you get rid of your `std::memory_order_relaxed` and have it use the default `std::memory_order_seq_cst`. If we then have a thread that is in a call to `Flush()`, it may complete the `store` operations on `_write` and `_read`, and then be pre-empted. Another thread may then come along and call `Read()` or `Write()`, in which case you will be reading or writing the start value of the array, which is presumably not what you want. In a multithreaded environment, you want **everything** in `Flush()` to complete atomically - so this would require a `mutex` or a rethink of your design.

The same problems can happen with the `Read()` and `Write()` functions themselves.

The `RingBuffer operator=` suffers from this on both sides: threads could be trampling all over each other inside `Buffer::operator=`, giving you an inconsistent view of its member variables, and also potentially trampling over each other for any of the member variables in the `RingBuffer` itself. Even with locks, it is very, very easy to write `operator=` in an incorrect way. Generally, you will need to use `std::lock`, and acquire locks on both `this` AND the argument to `operator=`:

```
RingBuffer& RingBuffer::operator=(const RingBuffer& buffer)
{
    // Assuming each has a mutable std::mutex called mutex
    // Need to use std::lock here to make sure things are always
    // locked in the same order, so we can't deadlock
    std::lock(mutex, buffer.mutex);
    // Probably want to add each to a std::lock_guard<> here
    // to make sure they are properly unlocked on scope exit.

    // Now we can safely perform the actual operator= operations...
}
```

The thing to take away from this is that writing lock-free data structures is **hard**. It is not sufficient to simply use a few atomic variables here and there in a multithreaded environment; thread pre-emption will cause all sorts of havoc if you aren't careful. Further, using `std::memory_order_relaxed` makes things very, very hard to reason about, and is best avoided.

Unfortunately, you may have to rethink the design of this. For a single threaded buffer it will work, but using `std::atomic` is unnecessary. In a multithreaded environment, this has a number of problems.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the remars of @Yuushi, there's some other stuff to improve:

- Your code doesn't respect SRP: the `Buffer` class should either manage low level memory (I'm looking at `DSG::DSGSample* Buffer::_buffer;`), or be a base for buffer specializations (but probably, not both). Since it is a base class, it should also not mix the responsibilities of being a base class and a concrete object (unless you have really good reasons for that).

  I would simply change it to a `final` class, with no VTBL. Then, I would encapsulate it in client code.
- This interface is incomplete:

  ```
  Buffer& operator=(Buffer const& other);
  ```

  If you are working with a derived class, you will get your objects sliced. The duplication of an object's data for class hierarchies, is usually done using the clone pattern.
- The DEBUG macro use is redundant, because `assert` only means something in debugging configurations:

  ```
  DSG::DSGSample& DSG::Buffer::operator[](size_t const& index){
  #ifdef DEBUG // this shouldn't be here
      assert(index<_size);
  #endif // neither should this
     return _buffer[index];
  }
  ```
- Checking for nullptr before deleting a pointer is redundant:

  ```
  if (_buffer!=nullptr) { // this is unnecessary
      delete [] _buffer;
  }
  ```
- The interface is a bit ambiguous:

  ```
  inline bool Full()const;
  inline bool Empty()const;
  ```

  These functions seem opposite (judging by their names).

  ```
  friend bool operator>>(DSG::DSGSample const& signal,DSG::RingBuffer& buffer){
      return buffer.Write(signal);
  }
  friend bool operator<<(DSG::DSGSample& signal,DSG::RingBuffer& buffer){
      return buffer.Read(signal);
  }
  ```

  These functions are redundant (unless you maintain this paradigm accross anything that can get data from a DSG::DSGSample in the code base). They also break the usual signature of the "stream reading" operator, which is supposed to return the stream, for call chaining. As a rule, you should have one and only one way to do an operation.